# (range(3),range(3)) ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for x,y in (range(3),range(3)):
    print(x+','+y)
```

I wont a simple output of any pare of numbers something like that:

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    for x,y in (range(3),range(3)):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: `zip(range(3),range(3))`

Comment: First of all, `range(3)` will give you at most `2`, not `3`. Also, what is the output you expect? "something like" is not precise enough.

Comment: Mildly interesting: if you change `3` to `2` in your example it fails with another error :) Completly unrelated to the question.

Comment: try: for x in range(3): print(x,",",x)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Nice exercise for the reader to figure out what `x` and `y` are then. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the built-in method [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x,y in zip(range(3),range(3)):
    print(x, y, sep=',')
```